# How to inherit permissions from directories to files for two users

Tags: php, linux, permissions

I change permissions to a folder (uploads) in the web server for allow Apache user to upload files. 
I change the ownership of this folder to www-data:www-data and I add my user with setfacl to allow myself to rwx on it. 
From PHP I create folders under /upload and I copied the files that users uploads to that that folders. The problem is that the new directories are created with permissions to both users (me and www-data) but the files inside the folders dont inherit the permissions for me.
I tried everything but nothing works.

Comment: Files don't "inherit" permissions from the folder. If you want uploaded/copied files to have another permission than what they get, you need to set it in your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you with for the new files/folders to inherit permissions you should set the parent folder groupID with: `chmod g+s <parent_folder>`